# How do you add a blank commented line in T4 using Ghostdoc Pro in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, t4, stringbuilder, comments, ghostdoc

Inside of the "Rules" settings in GhostDoc Pro it allows me to use T4 to format my comments.  However it randomly adds line breaks(which I have sorted out), and also will not allow me to add a single line of triple forward slashes.

For example:

```
///======================================================
///Class:    TripleSlash
///                 //<-----How do I add just a blank line like so?
///<summary>
///          Class of the triple slashing breed
///</summary>
///======================================================
```

I have tried adding a StringBuilder.Append("///"); I have tried just simply adding the three slashes.  However it seems that GhostDoc Pro removes any line of T4 or C# code that would add a blank triple forward slash commented line.

I feel like I'm overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T4 for Ghostdoc does not support inserting a line break or a blank line.

sad day.